# Ffmpeg subtitle use all available frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to generate subtitles on a small black frame I want to later embed in a bigger video:

```
ffmpeg -t 184 -s 1920x420 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i /dev/zero empty.mp4
ffmpeg -i empty.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -vf subtitles=captions.fr_FR.srt:force_style='FontName=eras-bold-itc.ttf' out.mp4
```

The problem is, ffmpeg prints the subtitles in small at the bottom of empty.mp4, as it would do for a normal video.

Is there any way to tell ffmpeg to use the full clip area (1920x420) to print the subtitles?

If no, is there any way to specify the size of the bottom part of a regular video where the subtitles should stay (for instance, stay within 400 pixels from the bottom)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works here:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x420:d=184 -vf subtitles=subtitlefile.srt:force_style="FontName='/path/to/font.ttf'\,Alignment=10\,FontSize=100" out.mp4
```

You'll have to experiment with font size values, using the subtitle entry with the greatest no. of characters to ensure no subtitle gets clipped. `Alignment=5` is meant to center-align the text, but it doesn't work here. `10` does.

Comment: How to position from the bottom of the page with pixels or percent if alignment is 1?